# Can I let two overLapping buttons response to two events same time

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

There is two overLapping buttons written in class1 "init" method （bottom code），but the two buttons were added to（addChild）another class (class2)

if I press the button(buttons). Does the two buttons can response two events same time?

and I want button1 to response class1 method

button2 to response class2 method

what is the excellent way to do it?

```
-(id)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)aPoint Mene:(CCMenu *)menu Fun:(SEL)fun
{

id aTarget = [menu parent];

NSString * imageName = @"light.png";


CCSprite* sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:imageName];
CCSprite* sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:imageName];
self.flashitemSprite=[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:sprite1 selectedSprite:sprite2 target:aTarget selector:fun];
sprite1.visible=YES;
_flashitemSprite.position  = _flashSprite.position;
[menu addChild:self.flashitemSprite];


CCSprite* sprite3 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:imageName];
CCSprite* sprite4 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:imageName];
self.aItemSprite =[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:sprite3 selectedSprite:sprite4 target:self selector:@selector(distroy)];
sprite3.visible=YES;
_aItemSprite.position  = _flashSprite.position;
[menu addChild:self.aItemSprite];


return self;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried what happens? I bet that if you touch the overlapping area, only one button will recognize the tap. It will probably be the button which was added last.

Answer (score 1):

If the two buttons are 100% overlapping of the same size, then you obviously don't need two buttons.  Just have one button that calls two actions, either by using one action selector that calls another method, or by actually assigning two action selectors to the one control event.

From Apple's docs for the UIControl - (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents method:

> You may call this method multiple times, and you may specify multiple target-action pairs for >a particular event. The action message may optionally include the sender and the event as >parameters, in that order.

If the two buttons are not completely overlapping such that you would like three behaviors:  button1 (if touching the part of button1 that doesn't overlap button2), button2 (if touching the part of button2 that doesn't overlap button1), button1 & button2 (if touching the overlapping part) based upon where the user touched . . .

then you should have code in the top-most button that tests the touch to see if it was inside the other button.  Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIView *button = (UIView *)sender;
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];
    CGPoint otherButtonLocation = [location locationInView:otherButton];

    if ([otherButton pointInside:otherButtonLocation withEvent:nil]) {

         [self otherButtonAction:otherButton];

    }

}
```

The above code is not tested and probably not optimal, but just a starting point to give you an idea.